# How should I perform research as an Undergraduate

Tags: soft-question, research-practice

Are there distinct fields or types of problems which have contributions that are realistic to achieve for an undergraduate?

Comment: I don't think there is any simple answer to this question.  Everyone has a different experience.  Sometimes undergrads work on research problems with a professor that they had for a course.  Or, they apply for REU's.  Or, they just read and talk about problems with friends.  Or, they work on challenge problems from kaggle.  I find that I learn a lot doing kaggle and I hear that some undergrad and grad students enjoy it.  I've been working on the Quora Question Pairs problem for several weeks now.  :)

Comment: Probably the most important thing is that while you're working on problems, don't isolate yourself.  I think it's quite valuable and fun to continue talking with others and expand your network.

Comment: @MichaelWehar even if it doesn't have a clear answer what if we could create a resource for this?

Comment: @MichaelWehar Create an list using this github template https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome

Comment: @JoshuaHerman If you start creating the list, then I will help add things to it.  :)

Comment: @MichaelWehar Ok fork this gist https://gist.github.com/zitterbewegung/ecc5e0f52c7d565f950fd59dc06d452b and add something to the list. Every time you add it then msg it to me and I will add them back to my copy of the gist.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ask your professor to give you a problem that you may solve as an undergraduate. You can also look for publications that say that the problems are appropriate for undergraduates.

I think that a research project that you could do that would be interesting would be to create a language that would compile to the EVM (I suggest scratch https://scratch.mit.edu/).

Another would be to explore user interface design for voice systems like making an Alexa App or one that you create yourself to solve some problem that you face.

A good example can be found at http://www.ics.uci.edu/~theory/269/020125.pdf

Comment: "look for publications that say that the problems are appropriate for undergraduates"
Could you provide examples?

Comment: I added an example. Do you have a field in mind ?

Comment: Theory of Computation (Recursion and Complexity theories). Also, Machine Learning. Could you pave me the way?

Comment: @MustafaTouny Oh, you should just go on kaggle and do some social network analysis of emails. Download https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/hillary-clinton-emails and then use the techniques in this paper https://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v23n2/hardin.pdf